# How would a Dyson sphere move our sun/solar system?

Tags: interstellar-travel

After watching "How to move the sun: Stellar Engines" (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3y8AIEX_dU) I still do not understand how the Dyson sphere would work.

It seems to me like you would sit on a raft and blow in your own sail, nothing much would happen?

At most the sphere would be pushed away by reflecting the particles, but that won't happen due to the sun's gravity. Hence, the forces on the sphere cancel out?

Comment: A Dyson sphere just collects power. Your question is really about using that power for a Caplan thruster or some alternative. (For example, the same video first discusses an option providing a slower acceleration, namely a Shkadov thruster.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural star spews matter and light equally in all directions. A star with (say) a hemisphere covered by a reflector emits nothing in the direction of the reflector and continues emitting in the other direction. Then the star-reflector system must recoil towards the reflector. (The star and reflector act just like any other rocket.)

Your reasoning is incomplete: the pressure from the star on the reflector is indeed balanced by the gravity between them, so the reflector and star are static relative to each other (note that this implies the pressure is greater than the gravity). But the pressure also applies to the star. The pressure on the part of the star under the reflector is balanced by gravity. And, most importantly, the pressure on the part of the star *not* under the reflector is not balanced within the star-reflector system. Therefore there is a net force pushing the system forward.

"Sitting on a raft and blowing your own sail" *does* push you forward if you are *also* blowing air off the back. And if you remove the sail, then you end blowing both forwards and backwards and you don't move at all.